# Unable to run Cloudfoundry UAA on local machine

Tags: java, cloudfoundry-uaa

I tried to follow the instructions in https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa, namely cloning the github repository and then executing the `gradlew run` command. I am running this on a Windows 10 system that has Java 1.8 installed. However, I run into the following error at around 97% of the execution of gradlew run.

> org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Deployable [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [120000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
>   :cargoRunLocal FAILED
>   :cargoRunLocal took 164921ms
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I am new to the Java ecosystem and I am not sure what the issue is. I tried looking up for increasing the timeout as seems to be the initial observation from the issue. I am not sure where to do this. I do not know if the issue is from a completely different reason.

Any suggestions would help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like process is getting timed out before it deploys the application, try increasing the timeout period in build.gradle file.

1. Open build.gradle in the root of the uaa
2. Search for below content:

   `cargo {
           containerId = tomcatContainerId
           port = 8080
       ...`
3. Increase the timeout by adding timeout = 180000

   `cargo {
               containerId = tomcatContainerId
               port = 8080
              timeout = 180000
               ...`